# Polymorphic checkbox create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association for playlist items. The type can be "Lesson" or "Cue". In my view I have a list of checkboxes since you should be able to add multiple items to a playlist at a time. Both "Lessons" and "Cues" at the same time.

The problem I'm having is letting the create action know which type each of the items added are. How can this be written in the controller? Currently each new entry have the type of "Lesson" since that's the first one listed.

```
CONTROLLER

params[:playlistings][:playlistable_ids].each do |playlistable|
  @playlist.playlistings.create(:playlistable_id => playlistable, :playlistable_type => params[:playlisting][:playlistable_type])
end

VIEW

<%= simple_form_for @playlistings do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :playlist_id, current_user.playlists.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, :required => true, :class => "form-control" %>
  <% for lesson in @lesson.sub_category.lessons.order(:position) %>
    <%= check_box_tag "playlistings[playlistable_ids][]", lesson.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :playlistable_type,:value => "Lesson" %>

    <% for cue in lesson.cues %>
      <%= check_box_tag "playlistings[playlistable_ids][]", cue.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :playlistable_type,:value => "Cue" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can create one virtual attribute in the model and update those records in using call backs.

You can create cue_ids as attribute accessor in the play listings model

```
attribute_accessor :cue_ids 

before_save :cue_ids
```

before save you can use this cue_ids and update the other model. You can create lesson_ids and cue_ids as attr_accesor.

Here you can get **playlistings.lesson_ids and playlistings.cue_ids**

Comment: Hey, my problem is how to make sure the create action know if the playlistable_id is a "Cue" or a "Lesson". For each checked option I need the id and the Type.